# Spark Error Writing DataFrame to LocalStack S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, localstack

I'm running LocalStack and attempting to write a DataFrame to S3 using the code below.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("LocalStack Test")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://0.0.0.0:4572")
    .config("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
    .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.sqlContext.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv("test.csv")

df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save(s"s3a://test/test2.csv")
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to verify integrity of data upload.  Client calculated content hash (contentMD5: 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg== in base 64) didn't match hash (etag: c20aef10d728c21878be739244ab1080 in hex) calculated by Amazon S3.  You may need to delete the data stored in Amazon S3. (metadata.contentMD5: null, md5DigestStream: com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream@2a6b3577, bucketName: spark, key: test/_temporary/0/)
```

Seems like this was a known issue that was recently resolved, but Spark still has trouble. Are there any additional configuration options I need to set when creating my SparkSession?

Answer (score 1):

"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint" is set to something odd...is this a local S3 server?

if so: trying forcing s3a down to v2 signing
`xml
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.signing-algorithm</name>
  <value>AWS3SignerType</value>
</property>`

I will not make any promises that it will work, only that it has been known to make the problem go away "once"

ps: CSV inferSchema is really expensive against S3, as the file will get read completely just to work out the schema, then a second time for the compute. Do it once, print the results, then use that schema from then on.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution, but got this Exception: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://[...]: getFileStatus on s3a://[...]: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: txfb723d20e28b4baa8456f-00633efc4a; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null:AccessDenied`.

Comment: welcome to debugging third party s3 stores. nothing else i can do